# TypeError: use() got an unexpected keyword argument 'item'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я изучаю slash команды в дискорде. Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

```
[WARNING] Failed to overwrite commands in <Guild id=972794759531872316> due to 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In 1.options.2.name: String value did not match validation regex.
...
TypeError: use() got an unexpected keyword argument 'item'
```

Дело заключается в самом последнем параметре - *item. Он обязан принимать всё. Как мне сделать, чтобы это работало?
Вот код:

```
from dislash import InteractionClient, Option, OptionType

#Активация предмета
@slash.command(
    name ="use",
    description="Используйте предмет(Подробно в help)",
    options=[
        Option('slot', 'Отсчёт слота начинается с нуля!', OptionType.INTEGER),
        Option('typeitem', 'Загляните в help!', OptionType.INTEGER),
        Option('*item', 'Выберите сам предмет', OptionType.STRING)
    ],
    guild_ids=idGuilds
)
async def use(ctx, slot = 0, typeitem = 1, *item):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async def use(ctx, slot = 0, typeitem = 1, *, item):
    pass
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/764917)